# Running multiple terminal commands in automator

Tags: automator

On my mac, I want to run an automator process to open terminal and execute several commands

"cd /Users/xxxx/Downloads/xxx-1.0.0"
then
chmod +x install.sh && chmod +x Launch\ xxx.command && sudo ./install.sh

how can I do this?

I've tried an apple script but can't get the syntax to work

Comment: What specifically isn't working?